# get count value by using MySQL in php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to write a very simple query in php.

```
$conn = createConnection();
$sql = "select count(username) from passenger where username = '$passengerId' and password ='$password'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$count = mysql_result($result, 0);

echo $count;
if ($count == 1)
    echo "true == 1";
else 
    echo "false != 1";

echo print_r(mysql_result($result, 0));
echo $count;
```

at the end, `echo print_r(mysql_result($result, 0))` gives me 1 as expected, but `echo $count` does not print anything. Also the if statement give me `false != 1`. I am not sure what kind of problem occurs here.

Comment: To be sure what's really there use `echo "<pre>[$count]</pre>";` or `var_dump($count);` instead of just `echo $count;`, you might get spaces, or other things.

Comment: `var_dump($count);` give me NULL. Do you know the reason?

Comment: use `mysqli` and enable `error reporting`.

Comment: @user3764319: Probably an error in your SQL command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$sql="select count(username) as totalUser from passenger where username = '$passengerId' and password ='$password'";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

// Associative array
$row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
printf ("%s",$row["totalUser"]);

// Free result set
mysqli_free_result($result);

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

See, if that solves your problem.

Comment: Is your sql query working fine? try that, see if you're getting any count value, even check values which you are passing in your where condition are available.

Comment: i think there might a database connection problem. is `mysqli` ok to create a connection?

Comment: Yep! Even you should use mysqli, with that check if your phpmyadmin is working

Comment: no it's not connection problem otherwise it would give Warning: mysql_connect(): Access denied or Warning: mysql_result() expects parameter 1 to be resource

Comment: Updated my answer, check now!

Comment: cool, your code actually works... my bad... Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

print_r will always return 1 when TRUE.

For example

```
print_r(mysql_result($result, 0)); 
// Equals this 
print_r(TRUE);
```

In above case both will return 1 and 0 for FALSE

But In your Case you use **echo and print_r together** which is also wrong. Basically your query not able to find any record from DB.

```
echo print_r(0); //will always return 01 use either echo or print_r
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is count will return either 0 or any integer value but the result set will always be there because either the row of result set will have any value or zero but the row would exist

Iterate over the result set and see if it is 0 or any integer value.